# How to use x3270 macros

Tags: terminal-emulator

I would like to run a macro when my 3270-terminal-emulator-program connects to the host in command-line.
This ability could be used to, for example, to automate the log-in to TSO using the x3270 emulator (by Paul Mattes).

To conect to the host I'm execute in command-line:

```
d:\alex\wc3270.exe 170.270.40.10  -port 23 -oversize 150x60
```

I would like something like this to connect and execute my macro:

```
d:\alex\wc3270.exe 170.270.40.10  -port 23 -oversize 150x60  -macro mymacro.txt
```

I have Microsoft Windows XP [Versión 5.1.2600] on my desktop PC.
I'm using the x3270 software: wc3270-3.3.12ga11-noinstall.zip  from http://x3270.bgp.nu/download.html
the wc3270 version is v3.3.12ga7 Wed Aug 24 09:36:34 CDT 2011 pdm

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of experimenting, including installing the latest version, I found the following lets me automate my logon to VM/CMS. Replace the strings myuserid and mypassword with yours. The \t tabs to the password field and the \n performs the ENTER.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\wc3270\wc3270.exe" -loginmacro myuserid\tmypassword\n +S